# Match arithmetic operators only one time foreach

Tags: python, regex

I have to match the following type of strings:

```
HELLO
HELLO+2.20
HELLO*1.10
HELLO+2.12*2.99
HELLO*2.30+5.40
```

The plus and star operator can be there only one time (with their respective amount) so

```
HELLO+2.20+3.50
HELLO*2.11+1.25*9.99
HELLO*3.33*4.44
```

aren't valid matches

I tried this regex:

```
([A-Z]{2,12}(\*(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?))?(\+(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?))?)
```

but matches only star operator first and plus operator for last (both optionally). This regex doesn't support this case:

```
HELLO+2.11*3.56
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the whole job has to be done with a single regex?  It would be *much* simpler to accept either operator in both positions, and separately check those matched groups for inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` to match either of the 2 variations of `+` and `*`

```
^[A-Z]{2,12}(?:\+\d+\.\d{1,2}(?:\*\d+\.\d{1,2})?|\*\d+\.\d{1,2}(?:\+\d+\.\d{1,2})?)?$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]{2,12}` Match 2-12 uppercae chars
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\+\d+\.\d{1,2}` Match `+` 1+ digits `.` and 1-2 digits
  - `(?:\*\d+\.\d{1,2})?` Optionally match the same as previous starting with `*`
  - `|` Or
  - `\*\d+\.\d{1,2}` Match `*` 1+ digits `.` and 1-2 digits
  - `(?:\+\d+\.\d{1,2})?` Optionally match the same as previous starting with `+`
- `)?` Close group and make it optional to also match only 12 uppercase chars
- `$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8x4m1t/1)

Answer (score 0):

A more straightforward alternative with builtin features (without regex search):

```
test_str = '''
HELLO+2.20
HELLO*1.10
HELLO+2.12*2.99
HELLO*2.30+5.40
HELLO+2.20+3.50
HELLO*2.11+1.25*9.99
HELLO*3.33*4.44'''

valid_strings = [s for s in test_str.splitlines()
                 if s and s.count('+') < 2 and s.count('*') < 2]
print(valid_strings)
```

The output:

```
['HELLO+2.20', 'HELLO*1.10', 'HELLO+2.12*2.99', 'HELLO*2.30+5.40']
```